# change svg radialGradient inside a shadowRoot

Tags: javascript, svg

I have the following code:

```
<lottie-player id="head" src="./assets/gradis/face_round.json" background="transparent" speed="1" style="width: 300px; height: 300px">
  #shadow-root (open)
  <div id="animation-container" class="main" aria-label="Lottie animation">
    <div id="animation" class="animation" style="background:transparent">

      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1200 1200" width="1200" height="1200"
        style="width: 100%; height: 100%; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
        <defs>
          <clipPath id="__lottie_element_95">
            <rect width="1200" height="1200" x="0" y="0"></rect>
          </clipPath>
          <radialGradient id="__lottie_element_99" spreadMethod="pad" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" cx="-1"
            cy="-0.9950000047683716" r="494.7430114746094" fx="-0.3150197936550764" fy="-153.11209152463204">
            <stop offset="1%" stop-color="rgb(0,195,255)"></stop>
            <stop offset="29%" stop-color="rgb(0,97,255)"></stop>
            <stop offset="57%" stop-color="rgb(0,0,255)"></stop>
            <stop offset="76%" stop-color="rgb(128,48,224)"></stop>
            <stop offset="80%" stop-color="rgb(255,96,193)"></stop>
            <stop offset="88%" stop-color="rgb(128,105,190)"></stop>
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="rgb(0,113,188)"></stop>
          </radialGradient>
          <mask id="__lottie_element_101">
            <path fill="url(#__lottie_element_100)"
              d=" M467.45001220703125,0.004999999888241291 C467.45001220703125,3.615000009536743 467.4200134277344,7.224999904632568 467.3299865722656,10.8149995803833 C466.7799987792969,34.78499984741211 464.44000244140625,58.334999084472656 460.4100036621094,81.28500366210938 C460.4100036621094,81.28500366210938 460.4100036621094,81.29499816894531 460.4100036621094,81.29499816894531 C453.70001220703125,119.53500366210938 442.3500061035156,156.1750030517578 426.95001220703125,190.59500122070312 C426.95001220703125,190.59500122070312 426.95001220703125,190.59500122070312 426.95001220703125,190.60499572753906 C426.44000244140625,191.7550048828125 425.9200134277344,192.89500427246094 425.3900146484375,194.0449981689453 C351.70001220703125,355.364990234375 188.94000244140625,467.4549865722656 0,467.4549865722656 C-180.6199951171875,467.4549865722656 -337.3299865722656,365.0050048828125 -415.1499938964844,215.05499267578125 C-417.82000732421875,209.9149932861328 -420.3900146484375,204.72500610351562 -422.8599853515625,199.48500061035156 C-422.9200134277344,199.34500122070312 -422.989990234375,199.2050018310547 -423.04998779296875,199.0749969482422 C-441.5199890136719,159.89500427246094 -454.7099914550781,117.74500274658203 -461.70001220703125,73.5250015258789 C-465.19000244140625,51.48500061035156 -467.1300048828125,28.94499969482422 -467.4200134277344,5.985000133514404 C-467.45001220703125,3.994999885559082 -467.45001220703125,2.005000114440918 -467.45001220703125,0.004999999888241291 C-467.45001220703125,-2.505000114440918 -467.44000244140625,-5.034999847412109 -467.3900146484375,-7.534999847412109 C-466.8299865722656,-42.51499938964844 -462.44000244140625,-76.55500030517578 -454.6099853515625,-109.25499725341797 C-450.6099853515625,-125.96499633789062 -445.7099914550781,-142.3249969482422 -439.9700012207031,-158.28500366210938 C-421.1199951171875,-210.68499755859375 -393.1700134277344,-258.7349853515625 -358.0299987792969,-300.5450134277344 C-346.4100036621094,-314.375 -334,-327.5249938964844 -320.8800048828125,-339.9049987792969 C-237.16000366210938,-418.9849853515625 -124.2300033569336,-467.4549865722656 0,-467.4549865722656 C124.2300033569336,-467.4549865722656 237.16000366210938,-418.9849853515625 320.8800048828125,-339.9049987792969 C334.04998779296875,-327.4750061035156 346.5,-314.2749938964844 358.1600036621094,-300.3949890136719 C388.42999267578125,-264.364990234375 413.3500061035156,-223.6649932861328 431.70001220703125,-179.5749969482422 C441.1199951171875,-156.97500610351562 448.80999755859375,-133.48500061035156 454.6099853515625,-109.25499725341797 C454.6099853515625,-109.25499725341797 454.6099853515625,-109.25499725341797 454.6099853515625,-109.24500274658203 C463,-74.19499969482422 467.45001220703125,-37.6150016784668 467.45001220703125,0.004999999888241291z">
            </path>
          </mask>
          <radialGradient id="__lottie_element_100" spreadMethod="pad" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" cx="-1"
            cy="-0.9950000047683716" r="494.7430114746094" fx="-0.3150197936550764" fy="-153.11209152463204">
            <stop stop-color="rgb(255,255,255)" offset="0%" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
            <stop stop-color="rgb(255,255,255)" offset="40%" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
            <stop stop-color="rgb(255,255,255)" offset="80%" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
            <stop stop-color="rgb(255,255,255)" offset="86%" stop-opacity="0.5049999952316284"></stop>
            <stop stop-color="rgb(255,255,255)" offset="100%" stop-opacity="0.009999999776482582"></stop>
          </radialGradient>
        </defs>
        <g clip-path="url(#__lottie_element_95)">
          <g style="display: block;" transform="matrix(0.5199999809265137,0,0,0.5199999809265137,600,642.1569213867188)"
            opacity="1">
            <g opacity="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,3.8459999561309814,0)">
              <path fill="url(#__lottie_element_99)" mask="url(#__lottie_element_101)" fill-opacity="1"
                d="M0 0 M467.45001220703125,0.004999999888241291 C467.45001220703125,3.615000009536743 467.4200134277344,7.224999904632568 467.3299865722656,10.8149995803833 C466.7799987792969,34.78499984741211 464.44000244140625,58.334999084472656 460.4100036621094,81.28500366210938 C460.4100036621094,81.28500366210938 460.4100036621094,81.29499816894531 460.4100036621094,81.29499816894531 C453.70001220703125,119.53500366210938 442.3500061035156,156.1750030517578 426.95001220703125,190.59500122070312 C426.95001220703125,190.59500122070312 426.95001220703125,190.59500122070312 426.95001220703125,190.60499572753906 C426.44000244140625,191.7550048828125 425.9200134277344,192.89500427246094 425.3900146484375,194.0449981689453 C351.70001220703125,355.364990234375 188.94000244140625,467.4549865722656 0,467.4549865722656 C-180.6199951171875,467.4549865722656 -337.3299865722656,365.0050048828125 -415.1499938964844,215.05499267578125 C-417.82000732421875,209.9149932861328 -420.3900146484375,204.72500610351562 -422.8599853515625,199.48500061035156 C-422.9200134277344,199.34500122070312 -422.989990234375,199.2050018310547 -423.04998779296875,199.0749969482422 C-441.5199890136719,159.89500427246094 -454.7099914550781,117.74500274658203 -461.70001220703125,73.5250015258789 C-465.19000244140625,51.48500061035156 -467.1300048828125,28.94499969482422 -467.4200134277344,5.985000133514404 C-467.45001220703125,3.994999885559082 -467.45001220703125,2.005000114440918 -467.45001220703125,0.004999999888241291 C-467.45001220703125,-2.505000114440918 -467.44000244140625,-5.034999847412109 -467.3900146484375,-7.534999847412109 C-466.8299865722656,-42.51499938964844 -462.44000244140625,-76.55500030517578 -454.6099853515625,-109.25499725341797 C-450.6099853515625,-125.96499633789062 -445.7099914550781,-142.3249969482422 -439.9700012207031,-158.28500366210938 C-421.1199951171875,-210.68499755859375 -393.1700134277344,-258.7349853515625 -358.0299987792969,-300.5450134277344 C-346.4100036621094,-314.375 -334,-327.5249938964844 -320.8800048828125,-339.9049987792969 C-237.16000366210938,-418.9849853515625 -124.2300033569336,-467.4549865722656 0,-467.4549865722656 C124.2300033569336,-467.4549865722656 237.16000366210938,-418.9849853515625 320.8800048828125,-339.9049987792969 C334.04998779296875,-327.4750061035156 346.5,-314.2749938964844 358.1600036621094,-300.3949890136719 C388.42999267578125,-264.364990234375 413.3500061035156,-223.6649932861328 431.70001220703125,-179.5749969482422 C441.1199951171875,-156.97500610351562 448.80999755859375,-133.48500061035156 454.6099853515625,-109.25499725341797 C454.6099853515625,-109.25499725341797 454.6099853515625,-109.25499725341797 454.6099853515625,-109.24500274658203 C463,-74.19499969482422 467.45001220703125,-37.6150016784668 467.45001220703125,0.004999999888241291z">
              </path>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</lottie-player>
```

as you can see I have an svg inside a shadow root, I need to change the stop inside the first `radialGradient` but I can't use the `id`because this would change on every render.

I try the following but can access the svg neither the first radialGradient.

I try the following:

```
function loadHead() {
  const head = document
    .getElementById('head')
    .shadowRoot.getElementById('animation')
    .getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
  console.log(head);
}

window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
  loadHead();
});
```

But head is always empty,

I also try:

```
function loadHead() {
  const head = document
    .getElementById('head')
    .shadowRoot.getElementById('animation');
    .getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
    .getElementsByTagName('defs')[0];
    .getElementsByTagName('radialGradient').childNodes.length;
  console.log(head);
}
```

But can't got anaythig. Any suggiestion or help would be appreciate

Comment: Its a WebComponent, Robert. The shadowDOM is used for a reason. ``.shadowRoot.querySelector("radialGradient")`` should do it **provided** all DOM is rendered. Start by accessing it from the console

Comment: Thank so much @Danny'365CSI'Engelman that would help a lot